# Using RBF neural networks for testing

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I am trying to run this code [LINK](https://github.com/raaaouf/RBF_neural_network_python/) code on may laptop, I changed these package:

- from keras.engine.topology import Layer
- from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model

to these package to work on my machine:

- from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Layer
- from tensorflow.python.keras.models import load_model

and whenever I run a program, this part could not be executed:

```
#model already saved in file
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import  load_model

newmodel1= load_model("Zoghbio.h5",
                          custom_objects={'RBFLayer': RBFLayer})
print("OK")
```

And I get on this error: How to fix it please?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\pc\Desktop\Ali\RBFNetworks\RBF_neural_network_python-master\RBF_neuralNetwork .py", line 214, in <module>
    newmodel1= load_model("Zoghbio.h5",
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\saving\save.py", line 206, in load_model
    return saved_model_load.load(filepath, compile, options)
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\saving\saved_model\load.py", line 122, in load
    meta_graph_def = loader_impl.parse_saved_model(path).meta_graphs[0]
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\saved_model\loader_impl.py", line 115, in parse_saved_model
    raise IOError(
OSError: SavedModel file does not exist at: Zoghbio.h5\{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}
```

**UPDATED error:**

```
Save model to file C:/Users/pc/Desktop/RBFNetworks/RBF_neural_network_python-master/my_file.h5 ... Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\pc\Desktop\RBFNetworks\RBF_neural_network_python-master\RBF_neuralNetwork .py", line 214, in <module>
    model.save(z_model)
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 745, in get_config
    raise NotImplementedError(textwrap.dedent(f"""
NotImplementedError: 
Layer ModuleWrapper has arguments ['self', 'module', 'method_name']
in `__init__` and therefore must override `get_config()`.

Example:

class CustomLayer(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2):
        super().__init__()
        self.arg1 = arg1
        self.arg2 = arg2

    def get_config(self):
        config = super().get_config()
        config.update({
            "arg1": self.arg1,
            "arg2": self.arg2,
        })
        return config
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [code you linked](https://github.com/raaaouf/RBF_neural_network_python/) in another question you have:

```
# # saving to and loading from file
# z_model = f"Z_model.h5"
# print(f"Save model to file {z_model} ... ", end="")
# model.save(z_model)
# print("OK")

#model already saved in file
from tensorflow.keras.models import  load_model
newmodel1= load_model("Zoghbio.h5", custom_objects={'RBFLayer': RBFLayer})
print("OK")
```

It is giving you an error because you are trying to load a model that is never saved before. Simply uncomment the portion above:

```
# saving to and loading from file
z_model = "my_file.h5"
print("Save model to file {} ... ".format(z_model), end="")
model.save(z_model)
print("OK")

# model already saved in file
from tensorflow.keras.models import  load_model
newmodel1= load_model("my_file.h5", custom_objects={'RBFLayer': RBFLayer})
print("OK")
```

Of course it doesn't makes much sense to train, save and re-load the model right away. I think the author wanted to show how the model could be trained and saved, and then re-loaded avoiding training everything anew. You can load and use the saved model without training each time this way.

**Update (recap of the comments):**

The OP got another error indicating:

```
Layer ModuleWrapper has arguments ['self', 'module', 'method_name']
```

This can happen when `keras` and `tf.keras` imports are mixed. In this case you changed the imports from the originals because you were having issues with them, saying that they `could not be resolved`.

Eventually the solution was to use the original imports and fix the tensorflow installation. The optimal choice was to create a fresh environment and install Tensorflow from scratch, but the OP wasn't using any environment.

So the solution was to simply uninstall tensorflow with:

```
pip uninstall tensorflow
```

and install tensorflow again, but the gpu version this time:

```
pip install tensorflow-gpu
```

Comment: Could you see the updated error: this error happen after I uncomment the part of (saving to and loading from file)

Comment: That error can happen when you have mixed imports of `keras` vs `tf.keras`. By the way, why did you changed the imports to `tensorflow.python.keras`? `tensorflow.keras` is preferable. Did you had any problems using the original imports?

Comment: Yes, When I use tensorflow.keras I get on Import "tensorflow.keras.models" could not be resolved" and even when use tensorflow.keras I get on the same error

Comment: which version of tensorflow are you on? Do `import tensorflow as tf` and then `print(tf.__version__)`

Comment: This is the output: 2022-08-08 21:09:45.769098: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found
2022-08-08 21:09:45.769291: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
2.9.1

Comment: I suggest you to create a fresh environment with Conda or pip (I can give you more info if you don't know how), and then install tensorflow. I'm working on 2.7.0 and everything works fine, so try installing that version with `pip install tensorflow==2.7.0`. Then try using the original imports

Comment: Now the first step I will uninstall tensorflow ? can you give me more info ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247133/discussion-between-claudia-and-kayla).